# C# - UWP - HttpStatusCode enum NotFound turns into 0 after exiting a method

Tags: c#, uwp, enums, compilation

I have an HTTP call that returns 404 - NotFound from the server.

In my code, when I get a status code that is not (200 - OK), I throw a custom exception like this:

```
public class MyException : Exception
{
    public HttpStatusCode HttpCode { get; set; }

    public MyException(HttpStatusCode httpCode, string message) : base(message)
    {
        HttpCode = httpCode;
    }
}
```

In the caller method, we catch the exception, in this way:

```
  try
  {
    int userID = 123;
    HttpRequest req = ...;
    (HttpStatusCode httpRes, object res) = await SendRequest(req);
    return (httpRes, res);
  }
  catch (MyException e)
  {
    s_log.ErrorFormat("Cannot perform action for user {0} due to code {1}", userID, e.HttpCode);
    return (e.HttpCode, null);
  }
```

Inside the `SendRequest` method, we have a log that shows we have received `HttpStatusCode.NotFound`.
The following log is `Cannot perform action for user 123 due to code 0`.

This happens when the app is compiled using .NET Native Toolchain.

When the app is compiled WITHOUT .NET Native Toolchain, instead, the code works "normally", producing a log `Cannot perform action for user 123 due to code NotFound`.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thank you very much!!

==== EDIT ===============================

Per @roi request, here's the full code of the SendRequest:

```
 public async Task<(HttpStatusCode, T)> SendRequest<T>(HttpRequestMessage req, bool authenticateReq = true, int retriesIfFails = 2, TimeSpan? optionalTimeout = null) where T : class
{
  (HttpStatusCode resCode, string stringRes) = await SendRequestString(req, authenticateReq, retriesIfFails, optionalTimeout);

  // Parse response content:
  T responseData;
  try
  {
    responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(stringRes);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    // if the expected result is a string, just return it!
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
    {
      s_log.InfoFormat("Return of API is of type string");
      return (resCode, stringRes as T);
    }

    s_log.ErrorFormat("Cannot parse response for request {0}: {1} due to {2}", req, stringRes, e.Message);
    throw new MyException("Cannot parse response for request " + req + ":" + stringRes, HttpStatusCode.PartialContent);
  }

  if (responseData == null)
  {
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
    {
      s_log.InfoFormat("responseData is null and return of API is of type string");
      return (resCode, stringRes as T);
    }

    throw new MyException("Cannot parse response for request " + req + ":" + stringRes, HttpStatusCode.PartialContent);
  }


  return (resCode, responseData);
}

public async Task<(HttpStatusCode, string)> SendRequestString(HttpRequestMessage req, bool authenticateReq = true, int retriesIfFails = 2, TimeSpan? optionalTimeout = null)
{
  HttpRequestException lastExc = null;
  bool retry = true;
  for (int i = 0; i < retriesIfFails; i++)
  {
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
      try
      {
        if (optionalTimeout.HasValue)
          httpClient.Timeout = optionalTimeout.Value;
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(req))
        {
          if (response == null)
          {
            retry = false;
            s_log.ErrorFormat("Null response for request", req.RequestUri);
            throw new MyException("Null response for request " + req.RequestUri, HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
          }

          // Read response content:
          string stringRes;

          // Support for compressed responses:
          if ((response.Headers?.Vary != null) && response.Headers.Vary.Contains("Accept-Encoding") && !req.RequestUri.ToString().StartsWith("https://www.google.com"))
          {
            using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
              try
              {
                await response.Content.CopyToAsync(inputStream);
                inputStream.Position = 0;
                stringRes = await inputStream.DecompressGzip();
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                stringRes = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                s_log.ErrorFormat("Cannot parse response for request {0}: {1} due to {2}", req.RequestUri, stringRes, ex.Message);
                throw new MyException("Cannot parse response for request " + req.RequestUri + ":" + stringRes, HttpStatusCode.PartialContent);
              }
            }
          }
          else
          {
            stringRes = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            s_log.InfoFormat("Return of API [{1}]: {0}", stringRes, req?.RequestUri);
          }

          // Check status code:
          HttpStatusCode respCode = response.StatusCode;
          if ((respCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) && (respCode != HttpStatusCode.Created) && (respCode != HttpStatusCode.Accepted) && (respCode != HttpStatusCode.NoContent))
          {
            retry = false;
            s_log.WarnFormat("Request failed with code {0} due to {1}; url was {2}", response.StatusCode, stringRes, req.RequestUri);
            throw new MyException(string.Format("Request failed with code {0} due to {1}", response.StatusCode, stringRes), response.StatusCode);
          }

          return (respCode, stringRes);
        }
      }
      catch (HttpRequestException e)
      {
        lastExc = e;
        if (!retry)
          break;

        // recreate the HTTP request to retry:
        HttpRequestHeaders headers = req.Headers;
        req = new HttpRequestMessage(req.Method, req.RequestUri)
        {
          Content = req.Content
        };
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> header in headers)
        {
          req.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (lastExc != null)
  {
    s_log.ErrorFormat("Cannot send request to {0} due to {1}; inner exception => {2}; type of exception {3}", req.RequestUri, lastExc.Message, lastExc.PrintInnerException(),
      lastExc.GetType()?.FullName);
    throw lastExc;
  }

  s_log.ErrorFormat("We should not reach this point, something went wrong...");
  throw new MyException("Cannot figure out the response from the server", HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the code about what you did inside the `SendRequest` method? Is the httpclient API you are using come from the `Windows.Web.Http namespace`

Comment: Hi @RoyLi-MSFT, please find the edit with the relevant code. Let me know if you need more information thanks! Moreover, in the code, we are using System.Net.Http.HttpClient

Comment: `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` is .net API which might be not suitable for UWP scenario. Please try to use `Windows.Web.Http namespace` to see if native UWP api has the same issue.

Comment: Hi @RoyLi-MSFT. The same behavior happens with the `Windows.Web.Http` namespace. besides, we have successfully used this code for years now, in the UWP app, with no problems. Last point, this code with System.Net.Http.HttpClient works perfectly when compiled WITHOUT the .NET Native Toolchain. Any ideas?

Comment: `we have successfully used this code for years now` Does the code work in .NET Native before?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT yes it worked before.

Comment: That seems not to be a problem for UWP side since the code works before. Is there any change from the server?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I am sorry to say, but this is exactly a problem of UWP!! The server is completely outside the picture: it replies with the correct HTTP status code and its role finishes there. It is the behavior of the client code that is astonishing. It actually doesn't matter that the HttpStatusCode value arrives from an HTTP call to a server: the point is that a method X returns a specific value of an enum, but the caller of this method X sees a return value of 0, instead of the actual enum value. It is purely a problem of the .NET Native compiler.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT any further idea? Thanks!!